# New-SmbShare not updating 'Network file and folder sharing '

Tags: powershell, smb

I want to set up a SmbShare from Powershell, 
I have created the folder and changed the Advanced sharing,
but the 'Network file and folder sharing' is not updating. 
This means that other users on the network are unable to access this folder.

```
new-item -Name foobar -Path C:\ -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue -ItemType directory -Verbose
New-SmbShare -Name foobar -Path C:\foobar -FullAccess everyone -Verbose
```

How do I update the 'group or user names' in 'Network file and folder sharing'
(Other than with the GUI)

I have attached the GUI screenshots below.

It is updating the Advanced sharing as expected:
[image: Advanced Share]

But it is not updating 'Network file and folder sharing'
[image: Network file and folder sharing]

I would have expected to see this:
[image: Expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to do this though ACL rather than SMBshare.

I wrote a function to change the setting more easily.

```
Set-NetworkShareAccess -path "C:\foobara" -Confirm
```

My Function:

```
function Set-NetworkShareAccess
{
    [CmdletBinding(
        SupportsShouldProcess=$true, 
        ConfirmImpact='Medium'
    )]
    Param
    (
        [ValidateSet(
            'ReadData', 'WriteData', 'CreateFiles', 'CreateDirectories', 'AppendData',
            'ReadExtendedAttributes', 'WriteExtendedAttributes', 'Traverse', 'ExecuteFile',
            'DeleteSubdirectoriesAndFiles', 'ReadAttributes', 'WriteAttributes', 'Write', 'Delete',
            'ReadPermissions', 'Read','ReadAndExecute', 'Modify', 'ChangePermissions', 'TakeOwnership',
            'Synchronize', 'FullControl'
        )]
        $PermissionLevel = 'FullControl',
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $path = "C:\foobara",
        $User  = 'everyone',
        [ValidateSet('None', 'NoPropagateInherit', 'InheritOnly')]
        $recursive = 'None'
    )
    
    New-SmbShare -Name ([System.IO.FileInfo]$path).Name -Path $path -FullAccess $User | Out-Null

    $Acl = Get-Acl -Path $path
    $Ar = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule("$User", "$PermissionLevel", "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "$recursive", "Allow")
    
    
    $Acl.SetAccessRule($Ar)
    Set-Acl -Path $path -AclObject $Acl
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this out. Not sure but try incorporating this in your script 
Install-SmbShare -Name MyShare -Path X:\ -FullAccess 'Everybody'

Comment: Hi RaghuKeenLearner, 
I ran `help *SmbShare*`  and `Install-SmbShare` is not listed. 
if it helps I am running Powershell 5. 
Is `Install-SmbShare` a downloaded cmdlet?